# I am trying to get commit body from Grgit log is it possible?

Tags: git-log, grgit

```
Grgit.open(dir: repoDir).log {
    range 'origin/develop', branch
    maxCommits:
        num
}
```

Can I add some argument to get commit body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by the body. The log method returns a list of [Commit](http://ajoberstar.org/grgit/docs/grgit-core/groovydoc/org/ajoberstar/grgit/Commit.html) objects that all have `shortMessage` and `fullMessage` properties